# Logging data posted to a specific URL in Apache

Tags: configuration, logging, httpd.conf

I have been asked to create a logging solution for an AngularJS application on a large e-commerce site. The solution itself has been created but actual transmission of the log data to the server has been problematic.

I have been told that I **must** post the data to a specific url (eg ./logger) and that the data POSTed to that URL must go into the Apache log files (I know this is not a good idea) and that there is no alternative. I know this will require some module in Apache, but I am at a loss as to what.

I have tried mod_dumpio but it's limited in that it does not allow configuration for specific VHost or Directory directives this means sensitive data coming into other areas of the site would also be logged and the log files would become huge over time.

Has anyone ever done something like this?

Edit: for clarification, this solution is going to be running on a *live* environment.

Answer (score 2):

you're looking for [mod_dumpio](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dumpio.html):

> mod_dumpio allows for the logging of all input received by Apache
>   and/or all output sent by Apache to be logged (dumped) to the
>   error.log file.

You have to realize that it comes with a hefty price: lots of disk IO for all the requests to specified location and fairly sizeable logs. So best used in test environment or enabled only briefly.

Alternative to having entire site doing mod_dumpio is to spin a second instance of apache (on a different port) that will have it enabled, and forward only those requests that need logging over to that instance via `ProxyPass` or `RewriteRule ... [P]` (`[P]` stands for Proxy)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Please see the third paragraph in my question for why mod_dumpio didn't meet my requirements. Sadly this requirement is for a live environment (I know it's bad but the infrastructure team has dictated this to me). I will update my question to reflect that this is for a live env.

Comment: see the update above. I have searched for alternative solutions for *apache* myself and that is the only option I came across.